# Auto login with auth token or email and password

Tags: ios, authentication

My app login works by sending an http post request to the server with the login information (email and password), receives a authentication token, and then sends back the auth token to get the users information which is loaded on the profile page.

I'm not sure how to go about structuring the auto login process. I'm considering storing the auth key in keychain, and starting each opening of the app with a request to the server with the stored key, to retrieve the profile information.

Is this advisable? Or is it better to store the email and password, and go through the auto login process with those?

Is it okay to have an auth key permanently attributed to a user's information?

Answer (score 0):

To store secure information on iOS, use the Keychain API. Apple's Keychain already handles encrypting and decrypting data that your application stores in the Keychain. And Keychain will lock/unlock with the phone, that is, with passcode/TouchID/FaceID. I've worked on a couple of app in the past that used keychain to save a user's password. I used a wrapper library called PDKeychainBindings. Not sure if its still supported. But you could find tons of libraries on Github that wrap the Keychain API.

I believe some of the financial apps I use on a daily basis use Keychain to store my password. My experience with them is, I usually enter my password once, and then they present me with an option to use FaceID/TouchID in the future. At some point(say 60 days since I last entered my password), they invalidate the token and force me to re-enter my password and then re-authenticate with FaceID to auto-login in the future. You could do something similar to save passwords or other sensitive information in your iOS app.

> Is it okay to have an auth key permanently attributed to a user's information?

I would advise against this practice. When dealing with passwords or authentication, it is always better to have tokens expire after a certain time period. This way, you can always make sure the right user has access to the right data.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Modern Approach :**

Let me explain the best approach to handle the user authorization and token management inside app.

1 - **App Secrete key** -  Hardcode value  Ex : AppABC 
2 - **App Consumer Key** - Hard code value Ex : ConABC 
3 - **App Token** - Any Hard code token Ex : 127shdhgagsheydhsjashsye747ehd

A) Use api to retrieve the new app token via sending app secrete key, app consumer key and hardcoded token(any hash key). After each 30 days you need to hit auto refresh api to retrieve the latest app token.

B) Now in login api send that app token which is not expire and You generated from above scenario and pass username and password with app token and in api response You will receive **authorize app token** which you can store in app preferences use in any other api for authorization and consider your user as logged in user.

Now in the case where you need to fetch detail for logged in user just pass that authorized app token and for common api's just the app token.